# How to find the highest value in mysql database with php output (e.g. unique user-ID)

Tags: php, mysqli

i'd like to get the latest/highest userid from my database.
In this case, to echo the highest userid.

Thought about the MAX() function of php, but im not quite sure whether this should work..

Best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right

```
SELECT MAX(userid) FROM Table;
```

Edit:
This is an edited piece of code I use:

```
//DB variables
$Sserver = 'localhost';
$Susername = 'root';
$Spassword = '';
$Sdatabase = 'databaseName';
$Scharset = 'utf8';

//Set up the connection
$dsn = "mysql:host=$Sserver;dbname=$Sdatabase;charset=$Scharset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dbcon = new PDO($dsn, $Susername, $Spassword, $opt);

//SQL statement
$query = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT MAX(userid) FROM Table;");

//Execute query
if(!$query->execute())
{   
    //Query is not successful.
    die('mysql error')
}

//Fetch the results
$result = $query->fetch();
if(empty($result['MAX(userid)']))
{
    //Table is empty
}
else
{
    echo $result['MAX(userid)'];
}
```

Comment: But how to echo it :/?

Comment: WOW Thank you :) +1